# Is there a way to json_encode a complete object not only non private keys?

Tags: php

I have a db in my case its a Couchbase server and the result of a query looks like this.

```
object(Couchbase\GetResultImpl)#7 (9) 
{ ["cas":"Couchbase\GetResultImpl":private]=> string(12) "AAByrS9P+RU=" 
["data":"Couchbase\GetResultImpl":private]=> string(15) "{"name":"mike"}" 
["expiry":"Couchbase\GetResultImpl":private]=> NULL 
["key":"Couchbase\GetResultImpl":private]=> string(11) "my-document" 
["status":"Couchbase\GetResultImpl":private]=> int(0) 
["err_ctx":"Couchbase\GetResultImpl":private]=> NULL 
["err_ref":"Couchbase\GetResultImpl":private]=> NULL 
["flags"]=> int(33554438) 
["datatype"]=> int(1) }
```

when i use **echo json_encode($getResult)** i only get the flags and datatype. Is there a way to when json_encode to encode also private keys ?

Answer (score 0):

Create public method in your class to return all fields with json encoded. Like:

```
public function getAllFieldsWithJSONEncoded() {
    return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
}
```

Comment: I cant create a function in the class that returns the data as it is a 3 party library which regularly updates the code which would overwrite any changes i make to it

Answer (score 0):

Create a public function in the class.Use **get_object_vars()** php function to 
Gets the properties of the given object

Here is full example to get object data in json format.

```
<?php 
class GetResultImpl
{
    private $cas;
    private $data;
    private $expiry;
    private $key;
    private $status;
    private $err_ctx;
    private $err_ref;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->cas = "AAByrS9P+RU=";
        $this->data = '{"name":"mike"}';
        $this->expiry = null;
        $this->key = "my-document";
        $this->status = 0;
        $this->err_ctx = null;
        $this->err_ref = null;

        $this->flags = true;
        $this->datatype = 1;
    }

    // get the properties of the cuurent class in json format
    public function getDataInJson()
    {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}



// Create object
$object = new GetResultImpl("biriyani", "burger", "pizza");

echo "<pre>";
echo "<br>// print full object: <br>";
var_dump($object);

echo "<br>// Convert to json Result(Wrong result):<br>";
echo json_encode($object);

echo "<br><br>// Convert data to json using get_object_vars()(Right result): <br>";
$result = $object->getDataInJson();
print_r($result);
```

**=> RESULT**

```
// print full object: 

object(GetResultImpl)[1]
  private 'cas' => string 'AAByrS9P+RU=' (length=12)
  private 'data' => string '{"name":"mike"}' (length=15)
  private 'expiry' => null
  private 'key' => string 'my-document' (length=11)
  private 'status' => int 0
  private 'err_ctx' => null
  private 'err_ref' => null
  public 'flags' => boolean true
  public 'datatype' => int 1


// Convert to json Result(Wrong result):
{"flags":true,"datatype":1}

// Convert data to json using get_object_vars()(Right result): 
{"cas":"AAByrS9P+RU=","data":"{\"name\":\"mike\"}","expiry":null,"key":"my-document","status":0,"err_ctx":null,"err_ref":null,"flags":true,"datatype":1}
```